# Force-inlining a function in another translation unit

Tags: gcc, optimization, inline, compiler-optimization

I have a very time-sensitive function `f()` running on a real-time embedded system. This function calls a function `g()` from the ARM CMSIS-DSP library, which is supplied in source form by ARM and included in my project; thus, it is in a different source file from the one in which `f()` is defined. `f()` is the only place in this code where `g()` is called, so it's a perfect candidate for inlining. If the code is compiled with `-O3` but not `-flto`, `g()` is not inlined inside `f()` (checked by disassembling the code), and `f()` runs in 3.1 microseconds. However, when adding `-flto` to the compiler flags, `g()` is inlined and `f()` now runs in 1.8 microseconds.

For development purposes, I'd rather not leave `-O3` on all the time (I usually use `-Og`). With `-Og -flto`, and even `-Og -flto -finline-functions`, `g()` is not inlined and `f()` runs in 3.6 microseconds. Unfortunately, the application experiences problems when `f()` runs that slowly, problems that are solved when `g()` is inlined and `f()` runs faster. Adding `inline` to the definition of `g()` or the declaration in the corresponding header might work, however I'd like to avoid directly editing the CMSIS-DSP library source files, since I consider that bad software engineering practice (e.g. if a new version is released and I forget to port the changes to it, my application will break again due to lack of inlining).

Things I tried which didn't result in the function being inlined:

- Adding `#pragma GCC optimize("O3")` before the definition of `f()`.
- Adding a prototype for `g()` with `__attribute__((always_inline))` right before I define my function.

How can I force `g()` to be inlined inside `f()` while keeping `-Og` for the rest of this code, without having to edit the CMSIS-DSP source files where `g()` is declared/defined?